# Index with ndarray/ tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I have a tensor A with shape (NB, N, 2, 2).

If I have a list B, consisting of indices with length NB that I want to keep in tensor A, how should I do that?
That is to say, I want to keep 1 (out of N) element per batch, based on the indices in B.

I can get it done with a for loop specifying the batch *i* in A, and the *i* th element in b. But is there a vectorized way to do it?

I tried A[B] or A[B.unsqueeze(1)], both had index errors. And A[:, B] would return NB elements for every batch.

Example:

```py
A = Tensor([[[a 2x2 mat AAA1], [a 2x2 mat BBB1], [a 2x2 mat CCC1], [a 2x2 mat DDD1]], 
    [[a 2x2 mat AAA2], [a 2x2 mat BBB2], [a 2x2 mat CCC2], [a 2x2 mat DDD2]], 
    [[a 2x2 mat AAA3], [a 2x2 mat BBB3], [a 2x2 mat CCC3], [a 2x2 mat DDD3]]
  ])

B = [1, 3, 0]
```

Expected output:

```
Tensor([[[a 2x2 mat BBB1]], 
    [[a 2x2 mat DDD2]], 
    [[a 2x2 mat AAA3]]
    ])
```

Answer (score 0):

[`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.gather.html) comes to rescue.

Prepare your index list like

```
# A.shape = (NB, N, 2, 2)
B = torch.tensor([1, 3, 0]) # should be of length NB
B = B[:, None, None, None].repeat(1, # your actual indecies in batch dim
                                  1, # indexing dim to be kept 1
                                  2, # these two must be repeated
                                  2)
```

And finally, use `gather` like this

```
torch.gather(A, 1, B) # indexing along '1'-th dim
```